# How can I quantify a Facebook page activity ? (graph API)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

For my business activity, I am establishing a prospects list with a general score describing how this prospect is promising regarding my activity.

I want one of the score's components to be **Social Networks Friendliness**. To evaluate this part, I would like to evaluate / measure / quantify social activity of my prospects by looking their business page activity.

This raises some questions :

- *Is this possible ?*
- *Should I use Facebook graph API ?*
- *Is it possible to know, for example, the number of posts per year of
  a public facebook page ?*

Comment: Since scraping is not allowed, it is either using the APIs – or doing this stuff manually in your browser :-) Number of posts is not directly available, so you would have to go through the whole feed of a page for a year. Of course that will only get you posts you can “see” - if they have targeted posts, you might miss those. And you’d have to get your app reviewed by Facebook for Page Public Content Access. A lot of trouble for a result of doubtful informative value, if you ask me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @misorude. Do you have any advice or alternative solution to evaluate the Social Networks Friendliness of a business through Facebook Graph API (or from an other way?) ?

Comment: You would need to start by defining what that actually _means_, and that is a step before we even get to any programming.